# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar "*" y "body" como elemento seleccionado para la propiedad box-sizing con el valor border-box?

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo layouts con flotantes en CSS y me ayuda mucho la declaración **box-sizing: border-box;** a la hora de visualizar y manejar bien mis elementos flotantes.

Pero me he encontrado con el problema de que cuando uso la declaración en **body**, no funciona para elementos hijos, pero cuando uso el asterisco sí funciona.

Mi hipótesis es que el selector "*" agarra todas la familia entera, padres e hijos.

Answer (score 1):

El `*` en CSS es un selector global, si lo usas solo colocando el `*` seleccionas todos los elementos a la vez, por lo que los estilos que agregues se aplicarían a todos los elementos. Puedes utilizarlo de otra manera para seleccionar elementos mas específicos, por ejemplo puedes utilizar el `*` y agregarle una clase, id o atributo para seleccionar todos los elementos que tengan esa clase, id o atributo, por ejemplo:

```
*[lang=en] {
    color: green;
}

*.text-red {
    color: red;
}

*#element {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: gracias Bryant, como siempre ayudando! 

Comment: De nada @zaraterdz siempre a la orden 

Answer (score 0):

En css se define a qué elementos se aplican ciertos estilos mediante un selector.

`*` es un selector especial. Es el [selector universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). Con él seleccionas absolutamente todos los elementos.

Puedes interpretarlo como un **comodín** o un **wildcard** si conoces Regex, scripting en terminal o otros lugares donde tenga un uso similar.

Así mismo puedes ser más específico. Por ejemplo, seleccionar todos los elementos con la clase `warning`:

```
*.warning {
   ...
}
```

Probablemente te suene parecido a simplemente escribir:

```
.warning {
   ...
}
```

Es porque, efectivamente. La misma documentación indica que ambas expresiones son equivalentes.

---

Por otro lado, al usar el selector `body` se están definiendo los estilos para ese elemento (o elementos en el caso de que haya varios) en particular.

Seguramente te encuentres con un caso como el siguiente:

```css
div {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h2> Texto </h2>
</div>
```

Acabo de decir que los estilos se aplican solo al elemento seleccionado. Naturalmente te preguntarás, entonces ¿Por qué el `h2` tiene el mismo color que el `div`?

La respuesta es simple. Hay propiedades que son **heredables**. En pocas palabras, una propiedad es heredable recibe el mismo valor que su ancestro más cercano tenga.

Esto no es realmente así. A lo que se refiere es que el comportamiento por defecto de la propiedad es tomar el valor del padre.

[Nota](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#notes): Puedes heredar explícitamente el valor de una propiedad estableciéndola en [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit).

[`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#formal_definition) es una propiedad heredable mientras que [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#formal_definition) no.

Comment: Excelente, entonces todo se reduce a que box-sizing no es una propiedad heredable, sólo aplicará para body y ya está, no aplicará para sus hijos. En cambio, con asterisco ya selecciono todos los padres, hijos y el árbol entero?

Comment: @zaraterdz absolutamente todo. Cómo mencioné puedes ser más específico. Supon que solo quieres seleccionar a todos los hijos (y demás descendientes) del body, tendrías que usar `body *`.